# Is the ending of the "Russian Doll" suggesting that the "good" timelines have joined?

Tags: russian-doll

In the Netflix TV series "Russian Doll", two people - Nadia and Alan are trapped in a time loop similar to one in the "Groundhog Day", except each loop ends with their death.

In the last episode

> Alan and Nadia are in the different timelines: Nadia is one when Alan was never trapped and vice versa and they figure out, that they have to prevent the first death that occurred to the other one.

In the last scene of the movie we can see that the screen is split in two: on one side there is "original" Alan and "changed" Nadia, in the other - "changed" Alan and "original" Nadia. In both cases they walk towards some sort of parade and... **the both parts of the screen merge together**.

Does that supposed to mean that the timelines have merged as well or  just that they've stumbled on the same event in the both versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

In this image we can see what each character is wearing in the alternate timelines, note Alan's scarf indicating the 'good' timeline one.
[image]

And here at the end we can see both 'good' timeline versions together by identifying their clothing (Alan is a bit hard to see, he's holding the flag to the left of Nadia):
[image]

Comment: Nice! I've never noticed that they were dressed differently and only the "good" versions remained!

Comment: That made me happy. I really enjoyed this show.